# Finding rows with MAX value after using GROUP BY

Tags: sql, datetime, subquery, max, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with 4 columns: `dept_no, emp_no, from_date, to_date`, where for each `dept_no`, `emp_no` is the manager.

I want to find current manager using `to_date`, and I want to display `dept_no` and `emp_no`.

Sample Data:

```
|emp_no  |dept_no  | from_date  |   to_date  |
| 11     | d001    | 1985-01-01 | 1991-10-01 |
| 12     | d001    | 1991-10-01 | 9999-01-01 |
| 21     | d002    | 1985-01-01 | 1989-12-17 |
| 22     | d002    | 1989-12-17 | 9999-01-01 |
| 31     | d003    | 1985-01-01 | 1992-03-21 |
| 32     | d003    | 1992-03-21 | 9999-01-01 |
```

Sample Output:

```
|emp_no   |dept_no  |
|12       |d001     |
|22       |d002     |
|32       |d003     |
```

I figured out this:

```
SELECT dept_no
     , emp_no 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT dept_no
            , MAX(to_date) as cur 
         FROM dept_manager 
        GROUP 
           BY dept_no) as new 
  JOIN dept_manager using(dept_no) 
 where cur = to_date;
```

I'm finding the `MAX(to_date)` for each department and then using it in `WHERE` clause.

This works but I feel that there should be better ways to do this.

I have seen many similar questions but none helped me as I want to display a column that can't be used in group by.

Comment: Please share some sample data and expected result. You can use row_number.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. Please tag only one database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A portable and usually efficient approach is to filter with a subquery:

```
select dept_no, emp_no
from dept_manager d
where to_date = (select max(d1.to_date) from dept_manager d1 where d1.dept_no = d.dept_no)
```

For performance with this query, you want an index on `(dept_no, to_date)`.

Another common approach is window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select d.*, row_number() over(partition by dept_no order by to_date desc) rn
    from dept_manager d
) d
where rn = 1
```

Depending on your database and version, there may be neater alternatives.

Comment: Filtering with a subquery works and seems like the best approach for what I want to do. Thank you.